# python's sphinx-build reformats rst files

Tags: python, python-sphinx

`sphinx-build` modifies the formatting of my RST files, and I can't figure out how to get it to stop. It only happens after I run `make html`, and my IDE (PyCharm) isn't doing the formatting.

Before `make html`:

```
General use plots
-----------------

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: generated/

    Study.plot_gene
    Study.plot_event
```

After `make html`:

```
General use plots
-----------------

.. autosummary::
:toctree: generated/

        Study.plot_gene
        Study.plot_event
```

This is my `make html` command (same as `sphinx-quickstart`):

```
html:
    $(SPHINXBUILD) -b html $(ALLSPHINXOPTS) $(BUILDDIR)/html
    @echo
    @echo "Build finished. The HTML pages are in $(BUILDDIR)/html."
```

And the full before/after, plus my `conf.py` are in: https://gist.github.com/olgabot/d8bb75b9d88bed19cb18

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the files are being edited in-place, then that is extremely surprising and — at a wild guess — would probably be because of one of the non-standard Sphinx extensions listed in your `extensions = [...]` list. To discover which one, you could try removing write permission from the `.rst` file, with a command like:

```
chmod a-w general_use_plots.rst
```

Unless the module attempting the modification is an exceptionally clever one, it will attempt the write without even checking the permissions bits first, and will be killed with an exception when it tries to open the file in write mode. You could then look at the stack trace and (hopefully) learn which extension’s code is incorrectly trying to touch your source.

If you do get a stack trace back, you could add it to the text of your question.

Comment: Turns out the problem was with PyCharm, not sphinx. "Reformat code before commit" messed up all my tabs!

Comment: Glad to hear that it was not Sphinx or one of its plug-in modules!